# how to use json array list in custom adopter in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-json

I want to call a json API from server in android:

[image]

**STEP1**

I have 2 list in one json.(menus and results)

```
{
"page": 1, 
    "menus": [ { m1:"v1" },{ ... },..., "count_menus": 10],
    "results": [ { r1:"v1",r2:"v2" },{ ... },"count_results": 273 ]
, "total_count": 5450, "total_pages": 283
```

}

**Question 1**:first, The json structure is true?

```
---------
```

I created an `MedicAPI.java` class:

```
public class MedicApi {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl("http://www.example.com/api/")
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

AND

```
public interface MedicService {

    @GET("service/last.php")
    Call<LastMedic> getTopRatedMovies(
            @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
            @Query("language") String language,
            @Query("page") int pageIndex
    );

}
```

AND Now, I created some models for that:

```
public class LastMedic {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private Integer page;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<LastMedicResult> results = new ArrayList<LastMedicResult>();
    @SerializedName("menus")
    @Expose
    private List<LastMedicMenu> menus = new ArrayList<LastMedicMenu>();
    @SerializedName("total_counts")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalCounts;
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalPages;


    public Integer getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public void setPage(Integer page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
    public List<LastMedicResult> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
    public void setResults(List<LastMedicResult> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
    public List<LastMedicMenu> getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }
    public void setMenus(List<LastMedicMenu> menus) {
        this.menus = menus;
    }
    public Integer gettotalCounts() {
        return totalCounts;
    }
    public void settotalCounts(Integer totalCounts) {
        this.totalCounts = totalCounts;
    }
    public Integer getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }
    public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }

}
```

AND also two models for menus and results as **LastMedicMenu** and **LastMedicResults**

So I think My code is complete for API.

Step 1, works in another project

---

**STEP2**

I use [this library adopter](https://github.com/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper/wiki/Use-it-custom-item-view-type).

this is my sample data in **Dataserver.java**

```
public class DataServer {

    private DataServer() {

    }

    public static List<MultipleItem> getMultipleItemData() {

        List<MultipleItem> list = new ArrayList<>();



            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                thisCounter++;
                list.add(new MultipleItem(MultipleItem.IMG_TEXT, MultipleItem.IMG_TEXT_SPAN_SIZE_MIN,"menu"));
           }


        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            list.add(new MultipleItem(MultipleItem.SERVICE_LIST, MultipleItem.SERVICE_SPAN_SIZE));
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
public class MultipleItem implements MultiItemEntity {

    public static final int TEXT = 1;
    public static final int TEXT_SPAN_SIZE = 4;
    public static final int IMG = 2;
    public static final int IMG_SPAN_SIZE = 1;
    public static final int IMG_TEXT = 3;
    public static final int IMG_TEXT_SPAN_SIZE = 4;
    public static final int IMG_TEXT_SPAN_SIZE_MIN = 2;
    public static final int SERVICE_LIST = 4;
    public static final int SERVICE_SPAN_SIZE = 4;

    private int itemType;
    private int spanSize;


    public MultipleItem(int itemType, int spanSize, String content) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
        this.spanSize = spanSize;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public MultipleItem(int itemType, int spanSize) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
        this.spanSize = spanSize;
    }

    public int getSpanSize() {
        return spanSize;
    }

    public void setSpanSize(int spanSize) {
        this.spanSize = spanSize;
    }

    private String content;
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }
}
```

Step 2, works for sample data.

for example I can binding XML with this code in adobter:

```
protected void convert(BaseViewHolder helper, MultipleItem item) {
        switch (helper.getItemViewType()) {
            case MultipleItem.TEXT:
                helper.setText(R.id.tv, item.getContent());
```

**STEP3**

Now, I want merge Step1 and Step2.

I means I want use json data instead sample data.

for example for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    thisCounter++;
                    list.add(new MultipleItem(MultipleItem.IMG_TEXT, MultipleItem.IMG_TEXT_SPAN_SIZE_MIN,"menu"));
               }
```

I want to use **menus** list in json.

and for this

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            list.add(new MultipleItem(MultipleItem.SERVICE_LIST, MultipleItem.SERVICE_SPAN_SIZE));
}
```

I want to use **results** list in json.

---

**Step 4**
Is this code is true to loads list form server?

```
callLastMedicApi().enqueue(new Callback<LastMedic>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LastMedic> call, Response<LastMedic> response) {


                List<LastMedicResult> results = fetchResults(response);
                List<LastMedicMenu> menus = fetchResults2(response);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LastMedic> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                // 
            }
        });

private Call<LastMedic> callLastMedicApi() {
    return medicService.getTopRatedMovies(
            getString(R.string.my_api_key),
            "en_US",
            currentPage
    );
}
```

if yes, how can use this code and DataServer class and MultipleItem class?

I want can do this (for example):

```
protected void convert(BaseViewHolder helper, MultipleItem item) {
            switch (helper.getItemViewType()) {
                case MultipleItem.TEXT:
                    helper.setText(R.id.tv, item.getMenu(M1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DataServer {

    private DataServer() {

    }

    public static List<MultipleItem> getMultipleItemData(List<LastMedicResult> results,List<LastMedicMenu> menus) {

        List<MultipleItem> list = new ArrayList<>();



            for (int i = 0; i <= menus.size(); i++) {
                thisCounter++;
                list.add(new MultipleItem(MultipleItem.IMG_TEXT, MultipleItem.IMG_TEXT_SPAN_SIZE_MIN,"menu"));
           }


        for (int i = 0; i <= results.size(); i++) {
            list.add(new MultipleItem(MultipleItem.SERVICE_LIST, MultipleItem.SERVICE_SPAN_SIZE));
        }

    }
}
```

after you do this please call the getMultipleItemData in your response

```
    callLastMedicApi().enqueue(new Callback<LastMedic>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<LastMedic> call, Response<LastMedic> response) {


                        List<LastMedicResult> results = fetchResults(response);
                        List<LastMedicMenu> menus = fetchResults2(response);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RECYCLERVIEW_ID);
                   final List<MultipleItem> dataList =     DataServer.getMultipleItemData(results,menus); //it will return a list and you can send this list in MultipleItemQuickAdapter

      /* i get this code from the library that you share above */
            final MultipleItemQuickAdapter multipleItemAdapter = new MultipleItemQuickAdapter(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, dataList); // your datas.
            final GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
            multipleItemAdapter.setSpanSizeLookup(new BaseQuickAdapter.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager, int position) {
                    return data.get(position).getSpanSize();
                }
            });
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(multipleItemAdapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<LastMedic> call, Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                        // 
                    }
                });

        private Call<LastMedic> callLastMedicApi() {
            return medicService.getTopRatedMovies(
                    getString(R.string.my_api_key),
                    "en_US",
                    currentPage
            );
        }
```